# Is there a way to call a already defined layout in another layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.innoversetech.hobuddies.MainActivity"
    android:background="#FF7506"
    android:id="@+id/linMatcher">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lin1">

<!-- Psychometric Questions-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/Surgency1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="I am the life of the party"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Surgency1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!--Radio Buttons-->
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Strongly Disagree"
                android:id="@+id/SD"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Disagree"
                android:id="@+id/D"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Not really"
                android:id="@+id/NR"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Agree"
                android:id="@+id/A"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Strongly Agree"
                android:id="@+id/SA"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What i want is to create 15 questions with similar radio buttons. Is there a way for me to create a radio button layout and just call it ? I wont have to copy paste the radio buttons again and again. Also how can I define each id's differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using `<include>` tag with adding layout to attribute `layout`.

**Try this:**

```
<include
    layout="@layout/your_layout">

</include>
```

**For example:**

**Here is your `radio_layout.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Surgency1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Radio Buttons-->
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Strongly Disagree"
            android:id="@+id/SD"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Disagree"
            android:id="@+id/D"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not really"
            android:id="@+id/NR"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Agree"
            android:id="@+id/A"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Strongly Agree"
            android:id="@+id/SA"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Here is your `acivity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.innoversetech.hobuddies.MainActivity"
    android:background="#FF7506"
    android:id="@+id/linMatcher">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lin1">

        <!-- Psychometric Questions-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/Surgency1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="I am the life of the party"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/radio_layout">
        </include>

    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

You can re-using layouts with **`<include />`** tag

If include layout should be used multiple times in target layout:

1. Create layout ***radio_btns.xml*** with **`<merge />`** tag as root

   `<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Strongly Disagree"/>
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Disagree"/>
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Not really"/>
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Agree"/>
       <RadioButton
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Strongly Agree"/>
    </merge>`
2. In main layout add **ViewGroup** items like **LinearLayout**, **RelativeLayout** or any **ViewGroup**:

   `....
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/first"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" />
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/second"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" />
    .....`
3. After **setContentView** in **Activity**

   `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    ViewGroup first = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.first);
    ViewGroup second = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.second);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_btns.xml, first, true);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_btns.xml, second, true);
    //Get any item to from viewGroup as child
    RadioButton firstInFirstGroup = (RadioButton) first.getChildAt(0);
    RadioButton secondInSecondGroup = (RadioButton) second.getChildAt(1);`
4. Do not use **id** in xml layout if you will include it to target xml multiple times. And note that first item index in **ViewGroup** is 0

Comment: I am getting error in these two lines ( Cannot resolve symbol 'inflate' and Cannot resolve symbol 'first' and 'seconf')
 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_q1.xml, first, true);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_q1.xml, second, true);

Comment: I fixed a typo. Try now.

Comment: I already had fixed the typos, yet still I am getting this error :/

Comment: Also sorry, the errors are  Cannot resolve symbol 'inflate' and Unknown class: 'first' and 'second')

Comment: I created an example and push it to github. [Include example](https://github.com/dsmail/android_example_include_multiple)